# Symfony 1.4 - Disable deafult language from url

Tags: symfony-1.4

I use http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/tmcI18nPlugin plugin for internationalization.

Is there a way do not show the default language in url?

for example if i have

```
  faq:
      url:    :sf_culture/faq
      param:  { module: faq, action: index}
```

English culture must miss for default language.